# How do I configure multicast to be used with rsync in batch mode

Tags: rsync, multicast

The rsync man page says "Multicast transport protocols can be used to transfer the batch update files in parallel to  many  hosts  at once, instead of sending the same data to every host individually." but I can't find any information about how to do that.  Can anyone reply with an example of how to do that or a URL which provides the information?

Comment: I guess a tftp client/server supporting multicast could be a good choice. For example: atftp / atftpd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`rsync`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html#BATCH_MODE) doesn't support multicast itself, it merely suggests multicast as a method to transfer the batch (delta) file:

> BATCH MODE
>
> **Batch mode can be used to apply the same set of updates to many
> identical systems.** Suppose one has a tree which is replicated on a
> number of hosts. Now suppose some changes have been made to this
> source tree and those changes need to be propagated to the other
> hosts. In order to do this using batch mode, rsync is run with the
> write-batch option to apply the changes made to the source tree to one
> of the destination trees. The write-batch option causes the rsync
> client to store in a "batch file" all the information needed to repeat
> this operation against other, identical destination trees.

> Generating the batch file once saves having to perform the file
> status, checksum, and data block generation more than once when
> updating multiple destination trees. **Multicast transport  protocols
> can be used** to transfer the batch update files in  parallel to many
> hosts at once, instead of sending the same data  to every host
> individually.

One way to use multicast is by using [TFTP with the experimental multicast option](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2090).

On Linux one such tool supporting the multicast option is `atftp` (client) / `atftpd` (server).

For example starting manually the server like this on a host reachable with IP address 192.0.2.2:

```
/usr/sbin/atftpd --daemon --no-fork --port 69 --tftpd-timeout 300 --retry-timeout 5 --mcast-port 1758 --mcast-addr 239.255.0.0-255 --mcast-ttl 1 --maxthread 100 /srv/tftp
```

will allow it to serve files in `/srv/tftp` using multicast.

An `rsync` command could include the option `--only-write-batch=/srv/tftp/foo` to make the batch available through the TFTP server, and then multiple clients could then download simultaneously the file `foo` (as `/srv/tftp/foo`) using multicast with:

```
atftp --option multicast --get --remote-file foo 192.0.2.2
```

If conditions are met, the server will server a single time the file to multiple multicast peers at once. The downloaded file can then be applied on client systems using the `rsync` option `--read-batch=foo` (or if still applicable, copying and using the `foo.sh` script created along `foo`, as documented in [BATCH MODE](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html#BATCH_MODE).)

---

Note: default Linux settings with *systemd* might prevent multicast to work. The systemd socket must listen only on IPv4 0.0.0.0:69 rather than on dual-stack IPv6 port 69, that's why I provided an example starting it manually (that should probably be preceded by `systemctl stop atftpd.service atftpd.socket`). `atftpd` doesn't support multicast with IPv6.